# How can we achieve solace message delivery of at least once with variable number of pods?

Tags: kubernetes, solace

We have a kubernetes deployment having 2 pods. We want to send messages to both these pods in 1:n way (each message should be received by both) and each message should be delivered at least once(QoS1).

To achieve the same, we have a topic and 4 queues created beforehand. All four queues are subscribed to the topic and hence receives messages from the same. We want to now startup the 4 pods and ensure that each of them consumes from 4 different queues. However, pods do not have any index and hence it is tricky to decide on which queue one has to subscribe from. Is there a way to check if a queue has active consumer before joining to ensure that it does not join an already consumed queue ?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: We used Gardener based clusters on AWS with latest K8S version. @MikołajGłodziak Curious to understand how would that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question precisely, but if you want to know if a flow is able to receive messages from a queue, maybe this [Active Consumer Indication](https://tutorials.solace.dev/jcsmp/active-flow-indication/) could help you.